# Cannot git pull due CONFLICT(MODIFY/DELETE) and symlink

Tags: linux, git, symlink

Our Laravel project is using symlinks. Recently when I tried to pull from my colleague's work, I get this message:

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): resources/lang/en/validation.php deleted in HEAD and modified in a262067feb430a072c1d3abf2ec500150212ff0f. Version a262067feb430a072c1d3abf2ec500150212ff0f of resources/lang/en/validation.php left in tree.
error: failed to symlink 'resources/lang/en/validation.php': File name too long
```

Upon trying to git rm the file, I am told it doesn't exist and is deleted in HEAD. Then when I pull I get the same message as above. Upon trying to `touch` the file and `git add` the file, and commit and then pull (in order to push my changes to the same branch), I get a similar error message:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in resources/lang/en/validation.php
CONFLICT (modify/delete): resources/lang/en/auth.php deleted in HEAD and modified in a262067feb430a072c1d3abf2ec500150212ff0f. Version a262067feb430a072c1d3abf2ec500150212ff0f of resources/lang/en/auth.php left in tree.
error: failed to symlink 'resources/lang/en/auth.php': File name too long
```

I have tried to skip-worktree the file, assume-unchanged the file and to change the git config setting via `git config --local core.longpaths true` to allow long-paths. None have worked. I think it has to do with the symlink, but I haven't run the script yet and so I don't know how this is a barrier to pulling for git.

When I do try to run the symlink, I get this error message:

```
error: unable to create symlink resources/lang/en/auth.php: File name too long
error: unable to create symlink resources/lang/en/validation.php: File name too long
```

Long story short, I cannot git pull, and therefore cannot git push. What's the solution? I don't want to `git push force` it.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the output of `git show a262067feb430a072c1d3abf2ec500150212ff0f:resources/lang/en/validation.php`?  Also, what file system are you using and what OS is your colleague using?

Comment: Thank you so much for supporting me and helping me with this problem, I think I'm good. I think I figured out how the answer because I reverted it by looking at the git history. It seems it was trying to make a symlink out of the content inside the file instead of the file name, which has thousands of characters, so perhaps the symlink script was bad. What would git show do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `git pull` is just running two Git commands:

- First, `git pull` runs `git fetch`.  This obtains any new commits needed for the second command.
- Second, `git pull` runs ... well, this can be complicated.  You are having it run the default, though: `git merge`.

Usually when `git pull` fails, one of these two commands that it runs is the one that actually failed.  The second command fails more often unless you have a particularly flaky Internet connection.  In your case, it's the `git merge` that failed.

The word *failed* is usually too strong, really.  Most merges do not actually *fail*.  They just stop in the middle of the operation due to a conflict (or two conflicts, in your particular case).  But your merge is a little special.  It really does have an internal failure, which repeats several times:

> ```
> error: unable to create symlink resources/lang/en/auth.php: File name too long
> error: unable to create symlink resources/lang/en/validation.php: File name too long
> ```

This is happening because your OS is placing a hard limit on the length of the target of a symbolic link.  As you found:

> It seems it was trying to make a symlink out of the content inside the file instead of the file name ...

Git's internal limits are much bigger than your OS's.

A symbolic link is just data, at one level, and that's how Git tends to store it (as a blob object, but one with `mode 120000` rather than the normal file mode of `100644` or `100755`).  At another level, the data will be interpreted as a file name, and that file name tends to have a length limit, such as 1024 or 4096 bytes.

> What would git show do?

`git show` will spill out the contents of the symlink, when pointed to a symbolic-link object.

```
$ git hash-object -w -t blob /usr/share/misc/termcap
d305cd8e161ecc8a78b0485d1926b9600efc6cb7
$ git update-index --add --cacheinfo 120000,d305cd8e161ecc8a78b0485d1926b9600efc6cb7,crazy
$ git commit -m "add crazy-long symlink"
[master dbb6e35] add crazy-long symlink
 1 file changed, 4725 insertions(+)
 create mode 120000 crazy
```

The normal tools will no longer work with this repository (which I made just to hold this crazy-long symlink):

```
$ git log | sed 's/@/ /'
commit dbb6e35967041fa4b03812866999ea0acd640dce
Author: Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Nov 15 19:52:05 2020 -0800

    add crazy-long symlink

commit c6e238c122dcd41410e7fdcfaa47ac112e935a35
Author: Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Nov 15 19:51:58 2020 -0800

    initial commit

$ git checkout HEAD^
```

This works fine, but trying to check out the second commit fails:

```
$ git checkout master
error: unable to create symlink crazy: File name too long
D        crazy
Previous HEAD position was c6e238c initial commit
Switched to branch 'master'
```

What happens at this point is that Git simply leaves the symbolic link out of the *working tree* entirely.  That's why it is in state `D`.  You can still do work with the repository, but you cannot use the regular tools in the regular way.

With your merge, what you can do is delete the bad symbolic links entirely (safely), create correct (good) ones, and add them.